# Anything in AWS Data Pipeline to stop execution of a certain activity with a decision making script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-data-pipeline

we have 5 pipes in our data pipeline which execute on following basis:
pipe 1 - pipe 4 = daily basis
pipe 5 - end of the month.

we are considering an option to create separate pipeline for pipe 5 as it doesn't have any dependency on other pipes.
Is there any way possible I can execute all pipes except pipe 5 with likes of a  decision variable as we have in OOZIE which can successfully ignore the execution of pipe 5 and complete the pipeline without any status of "error"/"Waiting on dependencies"?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off creating multiple pipelines and setting them on different schedules. If you'd like you spice things up you can use Cloudwatch scheduling and AWS Lambda to schedule pipeline creation/deletion in a cron-like way. You could also use AWS Step functions to define the workflow of each component.

Comment: thanks Fernanndo. we implemented same thing as you have suggested here.. but the real problem was: I need to execute 4 branches of a pipeline and stop execution of a single branch. we also did not figure out anything over this and created seprate pipeline for 5th branch.